# Routing in MVC application deployed on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, routes

I have added the following code

```
public class RouteController : Controller
    {
        public ContentResult GetImpression()
        {
           // Do something
        }
    }
```

In RouteConfig class i have added the following

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Impression",
                url: "imp",
                defaults: new { controller = "Route", action = "GetImpression", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I am expecting my `http://mymachine/imp` to work. What am i doing wrong? Do i have to do some settings in IIS as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For issues with routing I have always found the following [tool](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) from Phil Hacck to be invaluable in figuring out where I screwed up with my routing rules and what is getting called. There is nothing special you need to do in IIS to get things working. The one thing you probably should check is to ensure if your Application Pool is using version 4.0 and not version 2.0. Usually when you create a site in IIS it defaults the App Pool to 2.0.

Comment: Great tool. Thanks it was the ordering issue